# How can I display the values of another dataframe column as axis labels?

Tags: python, altair

**The data:**

```
d = {
  'name': ['Lynda', 'Sharon', 'Claudia', 'Jennifer', 'Lucy'], 
  'rank': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
  'hours_studied': [40, 60, 80, 20, 50]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

**The chart:**

```
bars = alt.Chart(df).encode(
        x='hours_studied:Q',
        y='rank:N'
    ).mark_bar()

regression = bars.transform_regression('rank', 'hours_studied').mark_line()

bars + regression
```

[image]

I want to display the `name` column values as **y-Axis labels** instead of the `rank` column values. If I change encoding channel `y` to `name` and use `rank` as the sorting variable, my regression breaks. How can I display the names as y-Axis labels while preserving the regression transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to directly re-map these labels to the values in another column. However, you can achieve what you want by hiding the axis and replacing it with a suitable text layer:

```
bars = alt.Chart(df).encode(
    x='hours_studied:Q',
    y=alt.Y('rank:N', axis=None)
).mark_bar()

regression = bars.transform_regression(
    'rank', 'hours_studied'
).mark_line(color='black')

text = alt.Chart(df).mark_text(
    align='right'
).encode(
    y=alt.Y('rank:N', axis=None),
    x=alt.value(-3),
    text='name:N',
)

bars + regression + text
```

[image]

---

Edit: to show the axis on the right side rather than the left side, you'll have to set the text position to the width of the chart in pixels. For example:

```
text = alt.Chart(df).mark_text(
    align='left'
).encode(
    y=alt.Y('rank:N', axis=None),
    x=alt.value(403),
    text='name:N',
)

(bars + regression + text)
```

[image]

Comment: It works but how do I move the text labels to the right side of the chart? I have tried using `configure_axisY(orient='right)` on the layerChart but it doesn't work.

Comment: The axis is hidden now, so orient won't do anything. If you want to move the text marks to a different x position, you can change their x encoding value. Setting it to the pixel width of the chart and changing ``align`` to ``"left"`` should work.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I have tried that as well. It moved the labels to the right side but they clip then. Setting `configure_view(clip=False)` didn't change that.

Comment: I was really puzzled as to why this works for you but not for me. Then I realised that you probably rendered this in Jupyter Notebook, while I work in Streamlit. I tried it and it renders correctly in JN for me too! Not in Streamlit however.

Have you had a chance to look at Streamlit already? The team there really seems to like Altair! However, their implementation still has a few bugs. I've already reported another one two weeks ago. Streamlit is really cool, I could see it potentially replacing JN (at least for some use cases).